# No exit option if something is running

Tags: java

How can I catch something going on if the user chooses the exit option from a menu?
I mean I'd like to be able to manage the event of a user who is going to close the application
but some activity is being performed so he/she shouldn't be able to exit.

Here's the code I wrote.
In a nutshell :

- recording is being performed --> user clicks exit --> WARNING "Process is running you can't do it"(The process goes on)
- nothing is running --> user clicks exit --> application closes

Is it possible to solve the problem by just adding a few lines of code without having to rewrite the 
entire program?

thanks very much in advance.
MAX

```
exitAction = new AbstractAction("Exit") {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        exitAction.putValue(Action.NAME, "Exit");
        // description 
        exitAction.putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Exit application");
```

Comment: Preventing user action is a bad idea. Instead, pop a dialog that tells the user what's happening and asks for confirmation that the program should exit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of your jobs in order to do this cleanly. If you can't you could try to iterate to all the jvm threads and looking to see if some of your worker threads are in a executable state or not.

Remember that the user cand kill the application with the big Task Manager axe if he so wishes :).

Comment: How do I check if a thread is running? that's a knotty problem for me.

Comment: Thread.isAlive() method ?http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive() ?

Comment: I tried this but I get errors
I don't know why
Error : --> non-static method isAlive() cannot be referenced from a static context

if (RecThread.isAlive()) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Warning !",
                        "Thread running", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    
} else {

System.exit(0);
}

Comment: @max You do need to get a reference to the actual thread object :).

Comment: Sorry for being a pain in the neck...but I still an error.The thread is called RecThread and that's the thread I'd like to detect....Thank you

Comment: That's probably the class name. `ClassName.methodName()` is used to invoke a static method defined in the class ClassName. The isAlive() is not a static method so it should only be invoked on an Thread instance.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'running' you mean unfinished threads, then you can loop all threads you have started and call `.join()`. before that display a message 'waiting for all threads to finish. Do you want to force close'

Comment: Would this work? From my understanding, invoking join() guarantees that the method will not return until the threads run() method has completed. As a result, if he shuts down his app and joins all the threads, he's going to have to wait for those threads to complete.

Comment: Join blocks the current thread. He can't proceed to the next line which is exit()

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable, a little flag, you set it to true at the begining of the process you wanna check, whe it ends set it to false.

Then in the closing event you can check if that variable is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using threads in your application (I am assuming you are, but am covering it for clarity's sake), then, when you exit out of your application, the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) will close down everything for you.

Otherwise, it is important that you correctly manage and track your threads in the system so that you can go and end them before you shut down the system. There are a number of ways to do this (PLEASE DO NOT USE `stop()` and try to avoid `destroy()`). My recommendation is that, within your threads, take the time to check to see if they should shut down (a flag that is set by the system upon shutdown is one such possibility). That way, you can clean up your threads, save any data (to a file or whatever, if that is what you need to do), and then cleanly shut down.